# java: Thread Behaviour indicated by ReentrantLock Behaviour

Tags: java, multithreading, concurrency

I do not understand the logs from the following code section:

```
private InfoBox getInfoBox(Path p)
{

    try
    {

        String path = p.toString();
        Log.getLogger().info("getting info box at " + path);
        lock.lock();
        Log.getLogger().info("got lock" + path);

        JAXBContext jaxbContext = JAXBContext.newInstance(InfoBox.class);

        Unmarshaller jaxbUnmarshaller = jaxbContext.createUnmarshaller();
        InfoBox ib = (InfoBox) jaxbUnmarshaller.unmarshal(p.toFile());

        Log.getLogger().info("got info box");
        return ib;
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        Log.getLogger().error(e.getMessage(), e);
        return null;

    }
    finally
    {
        lock.unlock();
        Log.getLogger().info("released lock");
    }
}
```

*When all runs well*, the log entry appears as follows:

> [INFO] 2016-07-29 09:58:59,163: PersistenceThread.getInfoBox(PersistenceThread.java:618) PersistenceThread  getInfoBox getting info box at C:\Users\jake_000_filedump_infoBoxes\AccountExecutive1469777154904.xml
>
> [INFO] 2016-07-29 09:58:59,179: PersistenceThread.getInfoBox(PersistenceThread.java:620) PersistenceThread  getInfoBox got lockC:\Users\jake_000_filedump_infoBoxes\AccountExecutive1469777154904.xml
>
> [INFO] 2016-07-29 09:58:59,203: PersistenceThread.getInfoBox(PersistenceThread.java:627) PersistenceThread  getInfoBox got info box
>
> [INFO] 2016-07-29 09:58:59,207: PersistenceThread.getInfoBox(PersistenceThread.java:639) PersistenceThread  getInfoBox released lock

***BUT I have a strange anomaly***

> [INFO] 2016-07-29 09:59:16,079: PersistenceThread.getInfoBox(PersistenceThread.java:618) PersistenceThread  getInfoBox getting info box at C:\Users\jake_000_filedump_infoBoxes\AccountExecutive1469778628407.xml
>
> [INFO] 2016-07-29 09:59:16,084: PersistenceThread.getInfoBox(PersistenceThread.java:620) PersistenceThread  getInfoBox got lockC:\Users\jake_000_filedump_infoBoxes\AccountExecutive1469778628407.xml
>
> [INFO] 2016-07-29 10:01:36,926: PersistenceThread.getInfoBox(PersistenceThread.java:639) PersistenceThread  getInfoBox released lock

***NOTE***
Although the lock is acquired,
The InfoBox is NOT retrieved
An Exception is NOT Thrown
BUT
the lock is RELEASED one minute later.

Can someone explain to me the underlying processes that allows this to happen?

Finally, the anomaly in the log (above) is the last line of the log file. After that the Thread seems to be completely hung.

Comment: What happened in the method that called `getInfoBox()`? Because an `Error` throwable would not be caught by that exception handler and would crash the thread. (Perhaps it was a StackOverflowError or OutOfMemoryError)

Comment: One quick comment (and this is probably not the cause of your problem), but you should probably move the lines up to and including the `lock.lock()` call above the `try` block - if for whatever reason you throw an exception before calling `lock.lock()` and your `finally` block tries to unlock it, you'll throw an additional `IllegalMonitorStateException`.

Comment: @Kiskae, thanks. I am logging JVM memory. There are no memory issues (gigs to spare). Still, you may be onto something! I will review my Exception handling.

Comment: @Kiskae. This is probably the answer in my case and it is definitely an answer to this question. Why not post it as an answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the comments:

As you stated it did not finish all of the statements within the `try` block and did not execute the `catch` block. This probably means that something was thrown which was not an `Exception`-class Error, such as an `StackOverflowError`, `AssertionError` or `OutOfMemoryError`.
If the application did not crash and there were no logs then the `Error` was probably silently swallowed somewhere in the application, which will make this very hard to debug.

Comment: I am now trying to catch(Error err) at the end of every Threads run method. Is this the most appropriate place to capture Errors in a multithreaded application?

Comment: You probably shouldnt be catching Errors, since they are usually un-recoverable. Logging of unexpected exceptions should be done through the `Thread.setUncaughtExceptionHandler(...)` method. Just set a handler before beginning work in the thread.